# How to track / monitor changes in an online PDF file?

Tags: pdf, website, tracking

How to track / monitor changes in an on-line PDF file? Need to be notified when that happens.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can retrieve something like the headers and see the modified date? but you will need a script to do that.

You could use the response of a service like http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html

And read the line:

```
Last-Modified:·Thu,·31·Jan·2008·15:58:57·GMT(CR)(LF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is no easy way to do it.

You can consider using LaTex for PDF creation - you will be able to track the "source code" of the PDF as any other source (SVN/Git/ etc.).

You can also use use the [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) lib to convert PDF contents to plain text (which is easily track-able).

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you're trying to use a basic version of source control. This might be a bit too large/complicated for your needs, but have you considered checking in the file to a CVS/SVN repository and then having the users access it through a web interface?